# Is this code harmful? Why?

Tags: malware, javascript, spyware

Code: http://pastebin.com/kJ8ZGP82

That code gets retrived from http://ui.sidepage.co for every HTTP page I visit (not HTTPS) and load it into the body tag of the page.

Is it harmful in any way? Please review.

Which part declares it's harmful nature?

One more thing...every HTTP request(not HTTPS requests) i make via browser goes though the following link...
http: //intad.pag2p.co/dva1/int.php?s=1&c=5&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.co.in%2F

In above, i was trying to visit http: //google.com

Don't know why all this happening.

```
var blacklistCheck;
(function () {
    function r(e, t) {
        for (var n in t) t.hasOwnProperty(n) && (e[n] = t[n])
    }
    function i(e, t, n, r) {
        if (e.addEventListener) return e.addEventListener(t, n, r), !0;
        if (e.attachEvent) {
            var i = e.attachEvent("on" + t, n);
            return i
        }
    }
    function s(t) {
        function r(e) {
            return Math.pow(e, .6)
        }
        var n = new Date,
            i = this,
            s = e.transitionSpeed,
            o = setInterval(function () {
                var e = new Date - n,
                    u = e / s;
                u > 1 && (u = 1), t.call(i, r(u)), u === 1 && clearInterval(o)
            }, 10)
    }
    var e = {
        baseDir: "http://ui.sidepage.co",
        version: "4",
        element: "S1D3P4G3",
        loadDelay: 3e3,
        displayDelay: 1e4,
        transitionSpeed: 300
    };
    e.location = e.baseDir + "/" + e.version + "/";
    var t = {
        hasInner: typeof window.innerWidth == "number",
        hasElement: document.documentElement !== null && document.documentElement.clientWidth,
        windowWidth: function () {
            return this.hasElement ? document.documentElement.clientWidth : document.body.clientWidth
        },
        computeShifts: function () {
            this.shiftX = this.hasInner ? pageXOffset : this.hasElement ? document.documentElement.scrollLeft : document.body.scrollLeft, this.centerX === !0 ? this.shiftX += this.windowWidth() / 2 : this.targetLeft > 0 ? this.shiftX += this.targetLeft : this.shiftX += (this.hasElement ? document.documentElement.clientWidth : this.hasInner ? window.innerWidth - 20 : document.body.clientWidth) - this.targetRight - this.node.offsetWidth, this.shiftY = this.hasInner ? pageYOffset : this.hasElement ? document.documentElement.scrollTop : document.body.scrollTop, this.targetTop > 0 ? this.shiftY += this.targetTop : this.shiftY += (this.hasElement ? document.documentElement.clientHeight : this.hasInner ? window.innerHeight - 20 : document.body.clientHeight) - this.targetBottom - this.node.offsetHeight
        },
        moveElem: function () {
            this.computeShifts();
            if (this.currentX !== this.shiftX || this.currentY !== this.shiftY) this.currentX = this.shiftX, this.currentY = this.shiftY, document.layers ? (this.node.left = this.currentX, this.node.top = this.currentY) : (this.node.style.left = this.currentX + "px", this.node.style.top = this.currentY + "px");
            this.node.style.right = "", this.node.style.bottom = ""
        },
        floatElem: function () {
            this.moveElem();
            var e = this;
            setTimeout(function () {
                e.floatElem()
            }, 50)
        },
        supportsFixed: function () {
            var e = document.createElement("div");
            e.id = "testingPositionFixed", r(e.style, {
                position: "fixed",
                top: "0px",
                right: "0px"
            }), document.body.appendChild(e);
            var t = 1;
            return typeof e.offsetTop == "number" && e.offsetTop !== null && e.offsetTop !== "undefined" && (t = parseInt(e.offsetTop, 10)), t === 0 ? !0 : !1
        },
        init: function (e, t) {
            this.centerX = t, this.node = e, this.currentX = this.shiftX = this.hasInner ? pageXOffset : this.hasElement ? document.documentElement.scrollLeft : document.body.scrollLeft, this.currentY = this.shiftY = this.hasInner ? pageYOffset : this.hasElement ? document.documentElement.scrollTop : document.body.scrollTop;
            if (this.supportsFixed()) this.node.style.position = "fixed";
            else {
                var n = this.node.style;
                r(this, {
                    targetLeft: parseInt(n.left, 10),
                    targetTop: parseInt(n.top, 10),
                    targetRight: parseInt(n.right, 10),
                    targetBottom: parseInt(n.bottom, 10)
                });
                var s = this;
                i(window, "scroll", function () {
                    s.moveElem()
                }, !1), this.floatElem()
            }
        }
    }, n = {
        init: function () {
            this.closeClicked = !1, this.transitionStatus = !1, this.buildElements(), this.buildLayout(), this.styleElements(), t.init(this.sp, this.centerX), this.registerMouseEvents(), this.finalize();
            var n = this;
            this.transitionTimeoutId = setTimeout(function () {
                n.initialTransition()
            }, e.loadDelay)
        },
        buildElements: function () {
            this.sp = document.getElementById(e.element), this.sp.style.cssText = "z-index: 2147483647; overflow: hidden; position: absolute; display: none;", this.side = document.createElement("div"), this.side.id = "sp_side", this.side.style.cssText = "position: relative; width: 20px; float: left;", this.open = document.createElement("a"), this.open.id = "sp_open", this.open.style.cssText = "background: url('" + e.location + "sp_sprite.jpg') no-repeat; display: block; opacity: 0.5;", this.close = document.createElement("a"), this.close.id = "sp_close", this.close.style.cssText = "background: url('" + e.location + "sp_sprite.jpg') no-repeat; display: block; opacity: 0.5;", this.bottomHover = document.createElement("div"), this.bottomHover.id = "sp_bottom_hover", this.container = document.createElement("div"), this.container.id = "sp_container", this.container.style.cssText = "position: relative; float: left;", this.iframe = document.createElement("iframe"), this.iframe.style.cssText = "position: relative; border: 0px;", r(this.iframe, {
                id: "sp_frame",
                frameborder: 0,
                marginWidth: 0,
                marginHeight: 0,
                scrolling: "no",
                allowTransparency: "true"
            })
        },
        registerMouseEvents: function () {
            function t() {
                this.style.opacity = 1
            }
            function n() {
                this.style.opacity = .5
            }
            var e = this;
            this.open.onmouseover = t, this.open.onmouseout = n, this.open.onclick = function () {
                return clearTimeout(e.transitionTimeoutId), e.transitionIn(), !1
            }, this.close.onmouseover = t, this.close.onmouseout = n, this.close.onclick = function () {
                return e.closeClicked = !0, clearTimeout(e.transitionTimeoutId), e.transitionOut(), !1
            }, this.iframe.onmouseover = function () {
                !e.transitionStatus && !e.closeClicked && e.initialTransition()
            }
        },
        finalize: function () {
            this.sp.style.display = "", t.supportsFixed() === !0 ? this.hasFixedSupport = !0 : this.hasFixedSupport = !1
        },
        initialTransition: function () {
            if (!this.closeClicked) {
                this.transitionStatus = !0, this.transitionIn();
                var t = this;
                this.transitionTimeoutId = setTimeout(function () {
                    t.transitionOut(), t.transitionStatus = !1
                }, e.displayDelay)
            }
        }
    };
    i(window, "load", function () {
        if (window.top === window.self) {
            n.centerX = !0, n.styleElements = function () {
                r(this.sp.style, {
                    left: "50%",
                    bottom: "-90px",
                    height: "90px",
                    marginLeft: "-374px",
                    marginRight: "-374px",
                    width: "748px"
                }), r(this.close.style, {
                    backgroundPosition: "-20px -40px",
                    height: "20px",
                    opacity: "0",
                    overflow: "hidden",
                    marginTop: "0px",
                    width: "20px"
                }), r(this.container.style, {
                    height: "90px",
                    width: "728px"
                }), r(this.iframe.style, {
                    height: "90px",
                    width: "728px"
                }), this.iframe.src = e.location + "page_old.html?t=" + this.sp.className, this.side.style.height = "90px"
            }, n.buildLayout = function () {
                this.sp.appendChild(this.container), this.sp.appendChild(this.side), this.side.appendChild(this.close), this.container.appendChild(this.iframe)
            }, n.transitionIn = function () {
                this.close.style.opacity = 1, this.iframe.style.opacity = 1, this.sp.style.bottom = 0
            }, n.transitionOut = function () {
                this.close.style.opacity = 0, this.iframe.style.opacity = 0, this.sp.style.bottom = "-85px"
            }, blacklistCheck = function (e) {
                e.value === "NO" && n.init();
                if (e.category) {
                    var t = document.createElement("img");
                    t.src = "http://c7.zedo.com/img/bh.gif?n=1668&g=20&a=" + e.category + "&s=1&t=i&f=1", t.width = "1", t.height = "1", t.border = "0";
                    var r = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
                    r && r.appendChild && r.appendChild(t)
                }
            };
            var i = document.createElement("script");
            i.type = "text/javascript", i.src = "http://bl.sidepage.co/?location=" + encodeURIComponent(window.location) + "&t=" + document.getElementById(e.element).className + "&callback=blacklistCheck", document.body.appendChild(i)
        }
    })
})();
```

Comment: My biggest concern would be why on earth it is being loaded into *every* HTTP page... who's injecting this content?

Comment: As @Poly says - this code could be changed at will serverside, so its content is almost irrelevant here. What is important is why and how it is getting loaded, and by who.

Comment: @RoryAlsop that's what i don't know exactly. It get's loaded both in firefox & chrome. I use Avast AV, SuperAntiSpyware, MalwareBytesAntiMalware & ran a HijackThis analyser on my system. My HijackThis analysis is here @ http://hjt.iamnotageek.com/log-1050735.html

Comment: @Polynomial I've started a discussion about this problem in Google Chrome user group in Google groups but to know help. Here is the discussion page http://productforums.google.com/d/topic/chrome/B7YYIWAzBcE/discussion

Comment: Please visit http://iamsrijit.wordpress.com/2012/09/14/ad-injected-by-isp-detection-prevention about a detailed report on this problem. It's a ad-injection campaign served by ISP.
See the article for more i

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The code doesn't look *particularly* malicious - it's some kind of ad injection / tracking. It almost certainly isn't trying to hit you with browser 0-days or steal your banking credentials. However, the big concern is that it's there in the first place, and that it's subject to change.

There are a few possibilities:

1. Your box is infected, and code is being injected at the socket level. There was a recent rootkit for Linux that does this quite cleverly, but since you're on Windows I guess it could be any number of different pieces of malware.
2. You have a dodgy toolbar or browser plugin that's doing this. If you've disabled all of that, this one's ruled out.
3. Your browser has been modified, either at the original source base or by a 3rd party, to inject this content. I highly doubt this, though there was a case like this with some Redhat package repo that got penetrated.
4. Your ISP is injecting the traffic.

I'd guess the 4th option is the most likely, if you've ruled out the first two. You should test this on other people's computers that also use the same ISP. If you can correlate the injection, you have evidence. At that point it's up to you as to what you do about it. You could complain to the ISP, but I doubt that would do much. Best option is to vote with your cash - switch ISP and make sure they know why, and be vocal about the issue on social media sites. You may even have legal recourse (depending on local laws and the ISP's contract) but you'd have to ask a lawyer about that.

Comment: Using firefox & it's freshly installed (no addons or toolbar). Checked the adbout:config too. But no mention of that domain.

Comment: I'd guess that it's the ISP then.

Comment: i've 2 ISPs & i live in India. Ortel & BSNL are the two ISPs I use. The script comes frequently when I use Ortel than BSNL.

Comment: A quick Google search for "ISP sidepage.co" shows that a few people have been complaining about it online. Contact your ISP and ask them if they're injecting it, and if so ask them to opt you out.

Comment: @BrianAdkinsm, take it easy, buddy. It's only been a couple of hours since this answer was posted.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that a [similar technique](http://blog.jgc.org/2011/01/code-injected-to-steal-passwords-in.html) was used by the Tunisian government to collect Facebook passwords sent via HTTPS. In my experience, having Javascript injected in your HTTP pages is almost always the work of your ISP.

Comment: may I know why the answer by me was deleted? It's the actual answer to my question.

Comment: @absk007 I didn't delete it (a moderator did), but in general an answer like the one you gave is typically done as a comment on the answer that helped you get to the solution, rather than posted as a separate answer.